# PHP regex on mention (@name)

Tags: php, regex

I have busting my balls on this one, and I have been trying numerous regex'es but just can't seem to get it right. (I am not that experienced in regex).

The following situation is going on, lets take this basic sentence for example;

`I recently saw @john-doe riding a bike, did you noticed that too @foo-bar?`

The trick here is to get only the `@john-doe` and `@foo-bar` parts from the string, preferably in an array:

```
$arr = [
   '@john-doe',
   '@foo-bar'
];
```

Could someone help me get on the right track?

Comment: Which regex expressions specifically have you tried? Paste them so when can figure out what is wrong with what you tried. Also, what are the allowed characters for the "mention"?

Comment: `/@[\w-]+/` should do the job

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like a simple regex

Comment: @anubhava I tried that one as well, but that only returns 1 item inside the array. Whilst there are multiple..

Comment: This is what I have tried:

```preg_match ("/@[\w-]+/", $content, $matches);```

Comment: Use preg_match_all

Comment: @DennisSmink use `preg_match_all`

Comment: And there is your problem. **Preg_match** is for one item. **Preg_match_all** is.. nah you can guess it.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed preg_match_all, thank you all! :)

Comment: And to follow up on isheggs question. What characters is allowed? Is @john_doe a match? @john-doe1? @i$hegg? What is the limits? Your regex is very narrow for what seems to be usernames.

Comment: Only a slugged string is allowed, so only A-Z, 0-9 and - characters are allowed.

Comment: \w will match underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex `(\@(?P<name>[a-zA-Z\-\_]+))` :

```
<?php
$matches = [];
$text = "I recently saw @john-doe riding a bike, did you noticed that too @foo-bar?";
preg_match_all ("(\@(?P<names>[a-zA-Z\-\_]+))" ,$text, $matches);
var_dump($matches['names']);
```

In this example, I used the `?P<names>` to name the capture groups, it's easier to get it.
 
I've made a Regex101 for you, and a PHP sandbox for test
https://regex101.com/r/ZFWvCG/1
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d04ce64a2a290994bf0effd7cf8f0039f20277b

Comment: `[\w-]` should suffice.

Comment: @ctwheels probably, many roads leads to Rome.

Comment: @Nicolas what if i want to avoid a email? if i write test@mymail.com it detects mymail as name